# Duality of maps on bounded vs trace-class operators (Schrödinger-Heisenberg dual)

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

$\newcommand\calH{\mathcal H}
\newcommand\calK{\mathcal K}
\newcommand\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}$I am looking for a (citable) reference for the following fact:

- Bounded linear maps $g:T(\calH)\to T(\calK)$ (bounded w.r.t. trace norm) stand in 1-1 correspondence with normal bounded linear maps $f:B(\calK)\to B(\calH)$ via $\tr g(\rho)a=\tr \rho f(a)$ for all $\rho,a$. (Here $T(\calH)$ are trace-class operators and $B(\calH)$ are bounded operators. And $\calH,\calK$ are Hilbert spaces.)
- And then $f$ is completely positive iff $g$ is.

This is mentioned as a standard result e.g. in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332543/textbook-covering-superoperators-and-tensor-products#comment829837_332543). I have seen $f$ referred to as the Schrödinger-Heisenberg dual of $g$ but all references were for finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces $\calH,\calK$.

Comment: I'm no  expert on this, but this correspondence looks suspicious to me. Suppose $\mathcal H$ is 1-dimensional and $\mathcal K=\ell_2$. Then your $g$ will just amount to an element of $\ell_2$, while your $f$ amounts a linear functional on $B(\ell_2)$. The latter can be wild, for example sending any bounded linear operator $X$ on $\ell_2$ to the limit, along your favorite non-principal ultrafilter, of $(Xe_n,e_n)$ where the $e_n$ form an orthonormal base for $\ell_2$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass the important word is "normal", which (I guess) means continuous for the weak-* topologies.

Comment: Yes, "normal" means weak*-continuous. Equivalently, "normal" means that SOT-limits of increasing nets are preserved. (Conway, A course in operator theory, Def 46.1) In particular, normal linear functionals on von-Neumann algebras (as in @AndreasBlass example) are of the form $a\mapsto\mathrm{tr}\, ab$ (Conway, Thm 46.4) which would exclude "wild" $f$'s.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh Unfortunately I don't have the time to write a proper answer, and probably won't for quite some time. What I had in mind is what is in section IV.2 of Schaefer's *Topological Vector Spaces*: If $E_1,F_1$ are in a dual pairing and so are $E_2,F_2$, then a linear map $f : E_1 \rightarrow E_2$ is weak-* continuous (*i.e.* continuous from $\sigma(E_1,F_1)$ to $\sigma(E_2,F_2)$) iff there is a linear map $g : F_2 \rightarrow F_1$ that is an adjoint with respect to the pairings.

Comment: It follows using some reasoning with the bipolar theorem that if, for each $i \in \{1,2\}$, $F_i$ is a Banach space and $E_i = F_i^*$ (the continuous dual space) then the adjoint mapping $g : F_2 \rightarrow F_1$ is bounded. If you want a reference from Schaefer, see IV.7.4, and use the fact that Banach spaces are Mackey, but it's actually easier to prove the special case of Banach spaces directly.

Comment: For positivity, you need the fact that the positive cone of $B(\mathcal{H})$ is weak-* closed (and the positive cone of the trace-class operators is norm-closed), and then you use the bipolar theorem. Then for complete positivity, you reduce it to the case of a positive map using the isomorphism $M_n(E)^* \cong M_n(E^*)$.

Comment: In [my thesis](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rfurber/phdthesis.pdf) I gave a full proof of the categorical duality between Banach base-norm spaces and what I called "Smith order-unit spaces", the latter of which were spaces that were the "generalized probabilistic theory" equivalent of W*-algebras (on p. 191, Theorem 3.4.5). I relate this to W*-algebras explicitly in p. 205, Proposition 3.6.2. For some reason I didn't explicitly state "the category of W*-algebras is dual to the category of preduals", though this was probably for reasons of space.

Comment: I had intended to include the case of complete positivity there, but I spent the time that I could have spent writing that on writing another chapter that I was later (unjustly) forced to remove. I also proved later on ([Counterexample 4.2](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.00210v1)) that I was right to use weak-* continuity instead of preservation of directed joins (known as Scott continuity in my community) because in the general case of an order-unit space these notions do not coincide. It follows that they also do not coincide in the completely positive case for operator systems.